# Understanding .NET GC and OutOfMemory Exceptions

Tags: .net, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I'm troubleshooting an OutOfMemory exception in my .NET 2.0 Windows Service application.  To understand the issue better I began by writing a simple .NET WinForm test app that generates an OOM Exception by building an ArrayList until an OOM Exception is thrown.  The exception is caught and logged and I can click on a form button to run the OOME again.  The strange thing I found was on the 4th run, the amount of memory consumed before the next OOME was roughly half.  The results listed below are consistent every time I run this.  Eyeballing TaskManager also confirms the behavior.  Unfortunately, Perfmon froze up when trying to get better stats.  Can someone explain why the memory limit is lowered after 3 runs?  My understanding of GC is fairly shallow.  You can also see I ran a GC.Collect() after a few more runs but it didn't help with the lowered limit.

UPDATE:  I also found a big difference using a const string vs a new object for each arraylist item.  Code is simply:

```
const string TEST_TEXT = "xxxxxxxxxx";
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
while (true)
{
    list.Add(TEST_TEXT);
}
```

---

Start Loop: memory 10,350,592

- OOM Exception Thrown
- Array Size: 134,217,728

End Loop: memory **550,408,192**

Start Loop: memory 550,731,776

- OOM Exception Thrown
- Array Size: 134,217,728

End Loop: memory 551,682,048

Start Loop: memory 551,813,120

- OOM Exception Thrown
- Array Size: 134,217,728

End Loop: memory 551,772,160

Start Loop: memory 551,903,232

- OOM Exception Thrown
- Array Size: 67,108,864

End Loop: memory **282,869,760**

Start Loop: memory 283,004,928

- OOM Exception Thrown
- Array Size: 67,108,864

End Loop: memory 282,910,720

GC.Collect manually triggered

Start Loop: memory **14,245,888**

- OOM Exception Thrown
- Array Size: 67,108,864

End Loop: memory **283,344,896**

Comment: what does your test program do exactly? How does it "build an array"?

Comment: Post your code, please.

Comment: See code example above.

Comment: String literals like that are interned. Each addition to your ArrayList only creates a new reference to the same block of memory (also, ArrayList is EVIL in .Net 2.0 and later: don't use it).

Comment: Just curious why ArrayList is considered Evil in 2.0+.  As compared to using the generic equivalent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are several points which, taken together, hopefully will give you enough information to answer your question:

- In spite of it's name, [OutOfMemory exceptions are just as likely to mean you are out of *Address Space* as physical RAM.](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx)
- GC.Collect does *not* collect all outstanding RAM.  Garbage collections in .Net are  *non-deterministic*, meaning there is no way to *force* the runtime to clean up all your RAM.
- The garbage collector in .Net is *generational*, meaning when an object survives collection it moves up to a higher generation, making it even less likely to be collected.
- By the time your OutOfMemory exception is thrown, your array has probably already survived a few collection attempts or was even moved to the LargeObjectHeap.
- Array sizes are fixed.  To add a new element to an array you must completely re-allocate the array. (You might get better test results using a structure like a list).

Answer (score 3):

Since you are building arrays, I assume that you are building one big array for each run. If this is the case it will be stored in the Large Object Heap (as it will be > 85000 bytes). LOH is not compacted like the generational heap, so the drop in size you're seeing is probably due to heap fragmentation.

Comment: There's little reason to use ArrayList these days, but it doesn't really make a difference in this case, casuse ArrayList uses arrays internally as well.